# Rails4 Upgrading Devise Extend Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

When Upgrading rails application from 3.2.17 to 4.0.4, I am getting this errors

```
default_controller_and_action': 'Sessions' is not a supported controller name. This can lead to potential routing problems. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use (ArgumentError)
```

In my routes file content

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "Sessions", :passwords => "Passwords", :registrations => "registrations" } , :path => '', :path_names => {
    :sign_in => 'login', 
    :sign_out => 'logout'
  }

  root :to => "children#index"
```

And SessionsController is extended from devise controller as follow

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
...........................
....................
end
```

Why I am getting Sessions is not supported controller name ? I have try to change it in routes and controller but still facing same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Solve this issues. This issues was due to case sensitive. We have to use small letter instead of Capital letter. For example, not Sessions but sessions. I was using Sessions in routes file but I have change it as sessions. The above code can written as

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "sessions", :passwords => "passwords", :registrations => "registrations" } , :path => '', :path_names => {
    :sign_in => 'login', 
    :sign_out => 'logout'
  }
```